# no matching distribution found for psycopy2

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I was trying to install psycopg2 via pip, but ended up with below error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install psycopy2
Collecting psycopy2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopy2 (from version
s: )
No matching distribution found for psycopy2

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psycopy2 != psycopg2`... you have a typo in your `pip` statement